# Authenticating user with grant oauth in android app. (my own API)

Tags: android, authentication, oauth-2.0, retrofit, okhttp

im begginer and I want a complete code.. I have a login page in android studio. and user gives his username and password. I have my own server and it's http and dont know how to use retrofit or okhttp or another library to authenticate user.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at this blog it will guide you very well

[Retrofit for beginner](https://medium.com/@prakash_pun/retrofit-a-simple-android-tutorial-48437e4e5a23)

Comment: its not Authentication. :(